# How to Update Migration DB Entity Framework in Server Production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have created a web-based application using Asp.Net MVC and Entity Framework 6. Currently the app has been installed on the production server my client. A few weeks ago, my client wants additional modules of applications that are already running today. Certainly in terms of programming code there are several additional classes of models and properties for the new table.
My question is:

1. How do I update the database schema in a production server, which of visual studio I do not have direct access to the existing database on the production server. This is the essence of my case..
2. Is there a way or a good move for my case. please his explanations and his guidance.

as additional information :

1. my Client apply a fairly strict security during the process of installing applications to a production server. Her intent is when the process of entering into the application server production not by me, but by their own internal teams with the reference of the installation documentation from my program.
2. Server application and database servers separately.
3. I use entity framework - code first (with DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges).

so many of my questions, thank you for all the attention and his answers. I really appreciate the time you spend in the form of answers that could provide a solution in the form of comment or opinion.
Thanks.

Comment: You want [Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) as you allude to in your question. You could either add migration code within the app, or turn initializers off (null) and provide a script to update the database. [See here.](http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/)

Comment: thanks @SteveGreene..i have read your link articel....but the article explains using visual studio, that is, my visual studio  should have access to the database ... here I can not directly for access to the production database ... is there a code trick should I apply when running the first time the application runs ..thanks for your comment ...

Comment: You don't need (or want) access to the other PROD database. Maintain a development environment with migrations. When you want to deploy, build your app and create a script that the DBA runs (update-database -Script). This will update the database schema and insert a record into __MigrationHistory that tells you it has been run.

Comment: I have yet to learn more on how to update-Database -script, I will try to more explore that function in EF.....thanks @SteveGreene for your time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OP 1 :**

> I use entity framework - code first (with
>   DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges).

**Ans :**

This is Wrong approach when you deal with the production database.What will happen to your production data on the db if you do this way ? All will be lost each and every time when you do the data migration.So the recommended way for production is `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`.

**[CreateDatabaseIfNotExists :](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)**

> This is default initializer. As the name suggests, it will create the
>   database if none exists as per the configuration.

**OP 2 :**

> How do I update the database schema in a production server ?

**Ans :**

You can create a Sql script using below command.After that you can use it to run on your production SQL sever.

Run this on the Package Manger console :

```
PM > Update-Database -Script
```

You can get more info here : [**Getting a SQL Script**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#script)

Comment: hi @Sampath...yes that true....i will be lose our data if i use CreateDatabaseIfNotExists,....but i have backup first the data before run application...i know that.....the problem its, I do not have direct access to the existing database on the production server...I have yet to learn more on how to update-Database -script, I will try to learn first ... but, if the process is in the DB server production will not be a problem with the application ..thanks for your comment.